# What is the poisonous spray that Jackal used on his car?

Tags: plot-explanation, props, the-jackal

In [*The Jackal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jackal_(1997_film)) (1997), Jackal sprayed something poisonous on his car.

[image: Reference Image 1]

So, when the hijacker came to steal his car, and touched the sprayed region, he immediately gets suffocated and
[image: Reference Image 2]

What is that poisonous spray Jackal used on his car which suffocates the hijacker, just by touch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be a concentrated dose of dimethyl mercury, a chemical which easily absorbs thru the skin and kills instantly.

A [chemistry professor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Wetterhahn) from a university in California had something like 1/1000 of a drop go thru her latex gloves (Yeah! She was wearing gloves and they didn't didn't help her). The drop fell on her gloved hand and rolled off onto the floor. She knew how dangerous it was so she immediately went to the E.R. but they couldn't help her. She suffered neurological damage, enetered a vegetative state, and died almost a year later when he life support was turned off.

There are so many aerosols that can kill a person. But here's a clue. There's a movie out there with a scene where someone is instructing a doctor on killing a dictator. This person tells the doctor that the stethoscope has a chemical on it and that all the doctor has to do it press it against the dictator's skin and he'll die immediately. I think the movie is [*Spy Game*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Game) (2001).

Comment: off-topic to the rest of your answer, but I'd say that the Jackal was not gay and that interaction was to show how much he was committed to his mission. Also adds shock value, a macho action movie star kissing another man... I don't recall seeing Arnold or Stallone doing that.

Comment: `I think the movie is Spy Game` - it is, love this film.